# Managing cron.*

Tags: cron, updatedb

I see that Ubuntu uses `/etc/cron.{daily,weekly,monthly}` for cron jobs. I also see that some things, like `updatedb` from `mlocate`, put their jobs there:

```
$ dpkg -L mlocate|grep y/m
/etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

Somtetimes, I would like to disable some of these jobs (`mlocate` in this case). I can obviously `sudo mv /etc/cron.daily/mlocate ~/cron.daily-dont-run` and be over with it. However, two questions:

- Is this how this gets managed? Is there something like `service` to manage SysV init scripts or overrides such as described in [Upstart intro, 10.41.1   Override Files](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id291)? I would like to tell it "OK, I don't want you to start", but without touching what is installed (see next item for one of the reasons)
- If I delete and then reinstall `mlocate`, I'll again get the cron.daily entry. Also, I guess (is this true?) upgrades will probably not go smoothly (e.g. it will make a cron.daily entry or maybe possibly break the package if there's something in the cron entry that it depends on).

If you do, how do you manage / deal with the things such as the above?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to `chmod -x /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate` . The cron script checks for the +x bit and will exit if it's not executable. Should be less intrusive than messing with the cron files, with the caveat that running updatedb.mlocate manually will be more complicated.

Comment: Copying the file elsewhere, then blanking the file should work. I don't know if this is true for cron jobs, but for config files, apt will present a diff of the two when updating. This should allow you to keep your blanked version (or not) without messing with the update process.